# Problem with fill between when using tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, lyx, texlive, fillbetween

Related to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184422/fillbetween-library-has-different-effect-based-on-plot-contents) question, my code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}

[domain=0:12, samples=100,grid=major,     
domain=1:4, xlabel=$\lambda$, ylabel=$f$, legend pos=north west, no marks] 

\addplot [red,fill=orange!70]    {(0.1)*x^8+x^3/3+(0.1)*x^2+5/3}; 

\addplot [blue,name path=A] {(0.1)*x^8-x^6-(0.3)*x^2-1}; 

\addplot+[name path=B] {0};     

\addplot+[gray] fill between[of=A and B,{domain=1:4}];

\legend{$f_1$, $f_2$} 
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

gave:

[image]

on one computer but fails on another one giving the message:

```
I can't find 'usepgfplotslibrarypgfplot.fillbetween.code.tex'.
```

I reinstalled Lyx and Texlive in the second computer but it returns the same.

What is happening?

Thank you.

PS: My preamble is:

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
```

I am working on Lyx but the code above is given inside a Latex frame (Control+L).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Without a full MWE my guess is, that you haven't written `\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}` but somewhere a typo ...

Comment: Sorry, but combining the codes to an MWE works as expected. Thus, this is most likely a problem with your TeX installation -- as you have already guessed yourself. But with that I cannot help you. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the attempt. Which could be the appropriate forum where solving this?